# Pass props to axios hook that implements react suspense

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, react-suspense

i have been trying to create a hook that fetches data and takes advantage of [react suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html#approach-3-render-as-you-fetch-using-suspense).
Using the example in the page (and [this article](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/how-to-improve-data-fetching-in-react-with-suspense-35b64990ad89)) I have created a function(i want to convert it to hook) that fetches data.

**Example**

[Here on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-galois-060ib?file=/src/ProfileDetails.js:0-35)

**Problem**

Currently I can't pass data through the function as it gets executed when it is called.I want to pass data in `useWrap(**HERE**)` and use it in `fetchData()`

**Expected behaviour / Target**

1. I want to pass data to useWrap() and put it in fetchData()
2. I want the useWrap to be a Hook in order to take advantage of basic hooks
3. I want to take advantage of React Suspense

Does someone know how to accomplish these needs and tell me what am i doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you and is more react-like than what you had originally.

Api.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useWrap(id) {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState({});
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
        .then(async (res) => await res.json())
        .then((result) => setApiData(result))
        .catch((err) => setError(err));
    })();
  }, [id]);

  return error ? error : apiData;
}
```

ProfileDetail.js

```
import React from "react";
import useWrap from "./Api";

export default function ProfileDetails() {
  const user = useWrap(1);

  if (user === null) {
    return;
  }

  return <div>{user.id}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for the answer but it doesn't work the way i wat as it doesn't trigger the Suspense

I added some logs to your example to let you see that the suspense is not triggered

[here in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-bhaskara-wycw3?file=/src/App.js)

Suspense doesn't trigger as in the `Api.js` is not thrown a promise as stated in the example of React Documentation